# Dagger 2 - Inject fields in activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mockito, junit4, dagger-2

Before I start, I've read a lot of tutorials but each of them contains info about old dagger - using `@builder` which is now deprecated. I'm using `@Factory`

What I have?

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

@Inject
lateinit var authService: AuthService

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
....
}
}
//----------------
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [TestAppModule::class])
interface TestApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<TestMyApplication> {
    @Component.Factory
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Factory<TestMyApplication>
}
//----------------
class TestMyApplication : MyApplication() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this)
    }
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerTestApplicationComponent.factory().create(this)
    }
}
//----------------
@Singleton
open class AuthService @Inject constructor(
    @AppContext val context: Context, private val authRemoteDataSource: AuthRemoteDataSource
) {
...
}
//----------------
class MockRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun onCreate(arguments: Bundle?) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build())
        super.onCreate(arguments)
    }

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestMyApplication::class.qualifiedName, context)
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

1. I show you, constructor in AuthService because it has more than 0 args
2. Mock runner applies my `TestMyApplication` class

And TestClass

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
    class LoginActivityTest {

@Mock
lateinit var mockAuthService: AuthService

@Rule
@JvmField
val activityRule = ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity>(LoginActivity::class.java, false, false)

@Before
fun beforeEach() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    Mockito.doReturn(NOT_SIGNED).`when`(mockAuthService).getUserSignedStatus(ArgumentMatchers.anyBoolean())
    println(mockAuthService.getUserSignedStatus(true)) //test
}

@Test
fun buttonLogin() {
    activityRule.launchActivity(Intent())
    onView(withText("Google")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
}
```

**What do I want?**
- In the simplest way attach mocked `AuthService` to `LoginActivity`

**What I've got?** Error:

While calling method:  `android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences`
In line:

```
Mockito.doReturn(NOT_SIGNED).`when`(mockAuthService).getUserSignedStatus(ArgumentMatchers.anyBoolean())
```

Method `getSharedPreferences` is called in real method `getUserSignedStatus`. **So now**, I'm getting an error because `Mockito.when` calls the real function which is public. I think, the second problem will be that mocked `AuthService` is not injected to `LoginActivity`

Comment: [google codelab on testing with dagger](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-dagger/index.html#13)

Comment: @sonnet really useful link, but I ask you one more, If I create `@Binds
    abstract fun provideFakeAuth(fake: LoginActivityTest.FakeAuthService): AuthService` there is a simple way to use other `FakeAuthService` in other test? Or I should create whole module from begin?

Comment: Maybe the best will be if I provide mock here and change return of methods in the next tests but how? -> How provide mock and fetch it in test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should probably provide the `AuthService` through a module, one for the normal app and one for the android test, which supplies the mocked version.  That would mean removing the Dagger annotations from the `AuthService` class.  I don't use `Component.Factory` but this example should be enough to for you to use as a guide.

In `androidTest` folder :

Create test module :

```
    // normal app should include the module to supply this dependency
    @Module object AndroidTestModule {

        val mock : AuthService = Mockito.mock(AuthService::class.java)

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        @JvmStatic
        fun mockService() : AuthService =  mock

    }
```

Create test component :

```
@Component(modules = [AndroidTestModule::class])
@Singleton
interface AndroidTestComponent : AndroidInjector<AndroidTestApp> {

    @Component.Builder interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance fun app(app : Application) : Builder

        fun build() : AndroidTestComponent
    }
}
```

Create test app :

```
class AndroidTestApp : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> =
            DaggerAndroidTestAppComponent.builder().app(this).build()
}
```

then the runner :

```
class AndroidTestAppJunitRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, AndroidTestApp::class.java.canonicalName, context)
    }
}
```

include in android closure in Gradle :

`testInstrumentationRunner "com.package.name.AndroidTestAppJunitRunner"`

add these deps :

```
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.27.0"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

then a test :

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) class LoginActivityTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity>(LoginActivity::class.java, false, false)

    @Before
    fun beforeEach() {
Mockito.doReturn(NOT_SIGNED).`when`(AndroidTestModule.mock).getUserSignedStatus(ArgumentMatchers.anyBoolean()
    }

    @Test
    fun buttonLogin() {
        activityRule.launchActivity(Intent())
        onView(withText("Google")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

Your dependency will then supplied through the generated test component graph to `LoginActivity`

Comment: Could I fetch Mocked `AuthService` in test before, activity starts?

Comment: No calling `rule.activity.authService` BEFORE `activityRule.launchActivity(Intent())` would be a NPE because it is supplied on onCreate through the AndroidInject.(this) line, afterwards is fine though. You can access your mock directly through the module, if you create a single instance of the mock in the module itself

Comment: updated to show how to access mock before the activity is launched

Comment: Right I did the same! Good Job :) Thanks